# Is there a simple way to repeat a php mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm hoping there's a little trick to php that will save me 100's of copy>paste>change-number - thanks for taking a look!

I've got a relatively large dataset in a MySQL db.

There are just two columns: Models (about 7000 unique entries) and Manufacturers (about 100 unique ones, i.e. the models are from just 100 different manufacturers)

At the moment (well, as I am writing the very slow, repetitious way), I have a huge list of PHP database queries along the lines of:

> $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE manufacturer ='3M'" );
>   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
>   echo $row['manufacturer'] . " " . $row['model']; }

What I'm doing is working, but is there perhaps a way of getting a list of all manufacturers then running the php above on the list?

Or maybe something different I haven't thought about?

Thanks heaps,

(The actual outputting is done into a javascript accordian - so displaying it on a single page isn't an issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique manufacturers

```
SELECT manufacturer
FROM products
GROUP BY manufacturer
```

But I'm not positive what you want the end result to be. Can you elaborate on that, and I'll provide a more concise answer?

**EDIT** This should do what you're looking for (or at least is a good base for you to play with). This will place manufacturers as the header of the accordion, then list the models within.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY manufacturer,product";
$lastMfg = null;
if (($result = mysql_query($sql)) !== false)
{
  echo '<div id="accordion">';
  while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false)
  {
    if ($row['manufacturer'] != $lastMfg)
    {
      if (!is_null($lastMfg))
        echo '</div>';
      echo '<h3><a href="#">'.$row['manufacturer'].'</a></h3>';
      echo '<div>';
      $lastMfg = $row['manufacturer'];
    }
    echo '<p>'.$row['model'].'</p>';
  }
  echo '</div></div>';
}
else
{
  echo '<p>MySQL Error: Unable to fetch products</p>';
}
```

Again, if you can be more clear, a better solution can probably be concluded.

Comment: Thanks Brad, sorry should've been clearer with intended end result. Basically I'm wanting a big list of manufacturers and when you click on one of the manufacturers it expands to show all available models. Your code displays all models under their manufacturer perfectly, but still haven't trouble with understanding the hierarchy of the code (i.e. to work out where to put the h1 accordion header)

Comment: After more faffing, I've got it working. Thanks so much, you rock!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch all the results from you database with 1 query, you can simply fetch all without a where clause and ordering by manufacturer, so you can "group" the rows in php. I understand this is you want, you should paginate anyway.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY manufacturer ASC;" );

$last_manufacturer = false; 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($last_manufacturer !== $row['manufacturer']) {
 //we got a different manufacturer since we ordered in alphabetical order
    $last_manufacturer = $row['manufacturer'];
    #... do something like put an separator between manufacturers
    # in this example we put a title, you should put the accordion markup or something similar
    echo "<h1> Manufacturer:", $row['manufacturer']  ,"</h1>";

}
echo $row['manufacturer'] . " " . $row['model']; 

}
```